# how to "blink" with newly added service in another section

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I have two sections: `combinedCriteria` and `filteredServices`. These tow sections are connected through knockoutjs script, when I hit click on any

item in filteredService section, it adds that service in above section called combinedCriteria:

```
<section class="combine-list-container" data-bind="visible: combineSchedules()">
    <ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: combinedCriteria -->
        <li>
            <span class="icon-delete" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteCombinedSelection"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: service.Name"></span>
            <span><span class="min emp" data-bind="text: service.Duration, visible: false"></span></span>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</section>
<section data-bind="visible: isServiceSectionVisible">
    <!-- ko foreach: filteredSerivces -->
    <header>
        <span data-bind="text: ServiceTypeName"></span>
    </header>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: GroupedServices">
        <li style="height:100%;" class="service">
            <a href="" data-bind="text: Name,click: $root.setServiceId.bind($data, Id), css: { 'activeservice': $root.selectedServiceId()==Id && $root.combineSchedules()==0 }"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

What I want to do, is when user clicks on some service in filtered services section, as it works now, to add it in above section combinedCriteria, **but to show short effect with some background graying, and then back as it was**.

```
function setServiceId(serviceId) {
            var helperId = serviceId;
            vm.selectedServiceId('');
            vm.selectedServiceId(helperId);
            vm.selectedServiceId(serviceId);
        }

serviceIdSubscrier = vm.selectedServiceId.supsendableSubscribe(changeServiceId);

        function changeServiceId() {
            var currentService = getService();
            if (vm.combineSchedules()) {
                var isShownMessage = null;
                if (vm.combinedCriteria().length > 4 && isShownMessage != true) {
                    var isShownMessage = true;
                    if (isShownMessage) {
                        var style = getDialogStyle();
                        theDialog = dialog.showMessage(vm.moreThen5SchedulesMessage(), ' ', [shell.cancelButtonText()], false, {
                            style: style
                        }).then(function (dialogResult) {
                            closeDialogForMoreThan5();
                            isShownMessage = false;
                        });
                    }
                   
                    
                }
                else {
                    vm.selectedService(currentService || {});
                    refreshAllowedTimes().then(function () {
                        setTimeByPreviousSelection();
                        checkToPushCriteria();
                    });
                }
               
            } else {
                refreshOnServiceType();
            }
        }       

function checkToPushCriteria() {
    //if (vm.combinedCriteria().length > 4) {
    //    var style = getDialogStyle();
    //    theDialog = dialog.showMessage(vm.moreThen5SchedulesMessage(), ' ', [shell.cancelButtonText()], false, {
    //        style: style
    //    }).then(function (dialogResult) {
    //        closeDialogForMoreThan5();
    //    });
    //}
    //else {
        if (vm.selectedService().Id) {
            vm.combinedCriteria.push({
                service: vm.selectedService() || {}
            });
            if (vm.combineSchedules() == 1) {
                withSuspendition(employeeIdSubscriber, function () {
                    vm.employeeId('');
                });
            }
            vm.selectedService({});

            refreshCurrentDate();

        }
    //}
}
```

so basically, in the function called `checkToPushCriteria()` I need to catch event when it adds to an array: `vm.combinedCriteria.push({service: vm.selectedService() || {}});`

I would probabaly add something like `jQuery(".someclass").css('background', 'red'); But I dont know which class is it (unkown identifier), also I dont know how to put highlight background color for some period of time (for example 0.5 seconds)`

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` binding has a few callbacks you can use for exactly this purpose, specifically: `afterRender` and `afterAdd`. [This piece of documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements) should probably help you along.

Here's a small example: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/9qarun4o/

Note that it's 2021 and there are nicer ways to make elements flash than using jQuery, such as CSS animations. But sometimes, you just gotta work with what you know/have...